# Checking battery and reception status in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm looking to create a simple Util class which has function that return various phone statuses, such as battery level, reception status, charger connected etc.
I do not want to monitor the status, only query it every once in a while (onButtonClick).

I haven't found a simple way to this without using intents and such. Isn't there any way to query a certain class?

I also do not know how to do it in a class which does not extend activity.

I am using Android API 8.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to. It's that it seems like an elaborate way to do a very simple task. Besides, as I've mentioned, I am having trouble using those code example in a separate class (Which does not extend activity).

Comment: Lets say I want to create the functionality in a separate class ( not a service). How do I transfer context to that class from the activity which holds an instantiation of it?